# Schedule List View items

Tags: android, listview, button, android-listview

I have a list view and two buttons(play & pause) I want that to when a play button touched a list view's first item go on top of page for example for 6 seconds and next item after first item be on top for 3 seconds and ...
This means Successively items go to top of list view's page and when I touch pause button it stop working and when I touch play button again it continue working

What can I do?

Sorry For my poor English 
Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can keep a track of the last visible item on the screen like a counter. On click of play button increase the value of counter by 1 and set smooth scroll to the counter value. Do this inside a Timer object pass a TimerTask to create a new timer object and schedule it to run over and over again. Hope this helps.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html